# Solving a Difference Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the solution $Y \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$  of difference equation $y(x+2) - y(x+1) + 2y(x) = x$ on  $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in [0,2): Y(x) =x$

This is all the information of the given question that I am trying to solve.

I need some help/guidance to help me solve this question and understand the solving mechanism of difference equations.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try getting rid of the $x$ by putting $g(x)+tx=y(x)$.

Comment: Do you mean I should substitute ${(g(x) - y(x)) \over t} = x$ or I should try iterating $g(x)+tx=y(x)$.

Comment: Substitute $g(x)+tx=y(x)$ for all $y$'s in the equation to get an equation in $g$ instead. Then pick a suitable $t$ to get rid of $x$. When you have solved it for $g$, you can obtain $y$ as $g(x)+tx$.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a try.